# Java plays audio on Windows but not on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, java

I've been writing for fun a Java program to play some tunes in .wav format.

Whilst developing, the audio played fine on my Windows machine, but however when trying the same code on Ubuntu the audio does not play. There are no errors logged to the console, I press the 'Play' button and nothing happens.

Here's the code I've been using, also contains some logging code:

```
try {
    System.out.println("All mixers:");
    for (Mixer.Info m : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        System.out.println(m.getName());
    }

    System.out.println("Default mixer: " + AudioSystem.getMixer(null).getMixerInfo());

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("bsc.wav"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This outputs:

```
All mixers:
Port HDMI [hw:0]
Port PCH [hw:1]
Port Snowball [hw:2]
HDMI [plughw:0,3]
HDMI [plughw:0,7]
HDMI [plughw:0,8]
PCH [plughw:1,0]
PCH [plughw:1,1]
PCH [plughw:1,2]
Snowball [plughw:2,0]
Default mixer: HDMI [plughw:0,3], version 5.3.0-51-generic
```

Thought this is more likely an issue with my setup than the code, so thought this was a fit for superuser. Did also write some code to try the other available mixers, but none of those worked either.

Looking around, did hear something about needing to install JMF but couldn't find whether it's really the solution.

Running Ubuntu 19.10 and Java 11.0.7 OpenJDK.

Edit1; found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) on StackOverflow about the Java Sound. Tried running the example code but also to no avail...

Comment: Most things have Java disabled by default these days.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is just a personal little project that I don't think I'd be releasing anywhere, and everything java should be a go on my machine

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple things to investigate and (probably) rule out.

- Is your button JavaFX? If so, have you verified JavaFX is working?
- Have you verified the address of the `File` object being created?
- Try using `URL` as your *AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream* argument, setting it with *class.getResource(URL)*.
- Use the *ais* to get a `Dataline.Info` object as part of the process.

The code for using Dataline.Info follows:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, ais.getFormat());
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(ais);
```

You might inspect the `Clip` in the debugger before playing it. Check the .audioData property, to verify the data was loaded into memory. You can also verify the audio format here.

I just went through a rigamarole trying to get a jar file made in Windows to execute on Ubuntu 18.04. It turned out to be JavaFX related actually. Once I fixed that, the program ran (including its audio). I always use URL when working with audio assets.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! To answer your first question, this is just a Swing application, no JavaFX.

Comment: Did some more testing, but unfortunately it seems possible to rule out both possibilities. The Clip object does appear to be populated (30,000,000 various bytes) so it seems the loading was working before (though you're right, getResource() is better), and switching to the DataLine code didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: This has gotten out of my area of familiarity. Since the Clip is populated, I'd next be tempted to try the different lines (mixers), rather than using the default. Have you checked/verified your ubuntu sound configuration? I have a sound card and have selected that device for output. For my Java, the default output mixer aligns. But I'm a bit shaky at working at this level. I'm not familiar with Snowball. Isn't that an AWS tool of some sort? Why is it listed as a sound line? (Too obvious: other apps produce sound okay?)

Comment: Hm, I did try each of the mixers but also unfortunately to no avail. Snowball is the name of a microphone I have plugged in (Blue Snowball). Tried running Minecraft and that could produce sound fine, but the example Java code given didn't..